# Tkinter Button events firing on load

Tags: python, events, button, tkinter

I have a quite simple programm so far that just has a few buttons with events on them. However when i run the programm the button events are firing once the buttons are initiated.

the troublemaking piece my code looks like this:

```
def initUI(self):

    self.parent.title("Windows")
    self.style = Style()
    self.style.theme_use("default")
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    abtn = Button(self, text="Open", command=load_file(area))
    abtn.grid(row=1, column=3)

    cbtn = Button(self, text="Close", command=self.parent.destroy)
    cbtn.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=4)
```

I ran it line for line and the load_file (it is an open file dialog and area is a canvas I initialised earlier) event is opening even before the next button is initialised or the window is visible.
To be as specific as possible: I dont want it to fire without me clicking the button. So what am I doing wrong here?

Edit:

This is the load_file event:

```
def load_file(area):
    fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("TIF", "*.tif;*.tiff"),
                                       ("GIF", "*.gif"),
                                       ("JPEG", "*.jpg") ))
    if fname:
        fname = fname.replace("/", "\\")
        print(fname)
        Images.path = fname
        import_file(fname, area)
    else:
        print "Could not open file ", fname

    return fname
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following line, the code does not `load_file`, but calling `load_file` and bind the return value of the function call.

```
abtn = Button(self, text="Open", command=load_file(area))
```

Replace it with function object using `labmda`:

```
abtn = Button(self, text="Open", command=lambda: load_file(area))
```

Comment: Its working, Thanks. I am just wondering why this is the first time i see this lamdba option after one hour of googling...

Comment: @Martin, Alternatively, you can define another function (let's call it `f`) that call `load_file(area)` instead of `lambda`, and pass `f` as `command` argument.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `command=lambda: load_file(area)`.

`command=load_file(area)` will call `load_file` and set the return value to `command`